# CSS Link/Hover Not Working

Tags: css, button, hover

I have a link which should display white for 'regular' and hover, and light blue for active.

But it shows purple for 'regular'. Why?

```css
  .button {
  text-decoration:none; 
  color: red; 
  background: purple; 
  }
  .button:hover {
  color: white; 
  background: purple; 
  }
  .button:active {
  color: red; 
  background: purple;
  }
  .button:visited {
  color: purple; 
  background: purple; 
  }
```

```html
<a href="example.com" style="text-decoration:none" class="button">text</a>
```

HTML:

```
<a href="example.com" style="text-decoration:none" class="button">text</a>
```

CSS:

```
<style>
  .button {
  text-decoration:none; 
  color: red; 
  background: purple; 
  }
  .button:hover {
  color: white; 
  background: purple; 
  }
  .button:active {
  color: red; 
  background: purple;
  }
  .button:visited {
  color: purple; 
  background: purple; 
  }
</style>
```

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce your problem, check this link https://jsfiddle.net/rfxb72fc/

Comment: You need to show some HTML markup that this would apply to. As far as I know without seeing some markup, you're making the mistake of using a `<button>` tag but styling it with `.button` _class_ selectors, which clearly won't work.

Comment: If this is on a link `<a>` as Matt assumes you need to say so, because then `:visited` is important.

Comment: @matt rohland, I've updated the code in question.

Comment: @stephen p, I've updated question's code.

Comment: Why is this question down-voted?

Comment: As a suggestion, it might help to clean up the CSS a bit. Unless there are some external styles also in play those duplicate definitions shouldn't be necessary. For example: https://jsfiddle.net/jnfnpLgj/1/

Comment: Definetly trying that @mattRohland

Comment: If I place :visited in first position, can I have all styling there, and then have only whatever changes for others, or do I have to declare everything specifically in the .button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `.button` is an `<A>` tag as your CSS suggests you might want to provide styling for the "visited" pseudo class.

See: http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Selectors/pseudo-classes/:visited

---

**Additional Information**

The cascading nature of CSS means that the style's order does matter.
Once a URL has been visited, the ":visited" styles will apply.
When you hover over the link, those styles will apply as well.
The priority in which they apply will depend on the order they are in your style sheet.

> **Note:** If you want ":hover" to be dominant (even after visited happens, it should be defined **below** `:visited`.

Comment: Seems that :visited over rides all other values. @MattRohland

Comment: The cascading nature of CSS mean that the order does matter. Once a URL has been visited the ":visited" styles will apply. When you hover over the link, those styles will apply as well. The order in which they apply will depend on the order in your stylesheet. If you want ":hover" to be dominant it's styles should be defined below ":visited".

Comment: So my guess is, visited should be first?

Comment: Tell if if it's the right place to ask: I'd like to have a different text appear once it's visited. In this case, "Subscribed!".

Comment: You can put the third comment in your answer, then I may mark it correct.

Comment: if you'd like me to mark your answer as correct, please add your third comment to it. Thanks.